# Administering Users in DNN 9.2

Tags: dotnetnuke, settings

I run a DNN site where we have used a 3rd party module for several years to let our client administer their own users.  Now that we are upgrading to DNN 9.2, that module no longer works, probably because of all the deprecated code.

I created a blank page, and added module "Users and Roles" to it.

Problem 1: It is not visible on the page, probably because it behaves more as a popup in the "admin" menu.

Problem 2: When I attempt to change that modules setting, I get an Exception:
`ModuleLoadException: The file '/DesktopModules/Admin/Security/UserSettings.ascx' does not exist'` Indeed, when I look for the file UserSettings.ascx it is nowhere to be found.

I need to give our client a way to edit their own users, without giving them Administrators privilege.  How can I fix these problems?

Comment: A couple questions. What is the module you were using before? Did the module work in version 9.1?

Comment: The module is effority.UserRolesManager.  No, it had a different problem in 9.1 that I could not track down.

Comment: I would contact the vendor if they are still around and see if they have a fix or can provide one. If not you may want to consider another module. I thought that DNN 9.1 added the ability for non-admin users to manage users but I can not find any new roles, so I must have been mistaken.